# WSO2 API Manager Certification exam

Tags: api, wso2, wso2-esb

I am planning to do WSO2 API Manager development certification. Could any body help me out with questions/dumps

Answer (score 1):

The link [1] contains exam content and documentation that can be used to prepare for the certification. The link [2] contains some of the sample questions that can be used to prepare for the certification.

[1]-https://wso2.com/training/certification/certified-api-manager-developer
[2]-https://wso2.com/training/certified-api-manager-developer-sample-questions